# CodeIgniter - Update() returns false even if the update has worked

Tags: php, codeigniter

My function works with any value of the parameter `$champ` except with the value "utilisateur" where the function returns false, even though the update works.

I've tried to use transactions to avoid the issue, but it's still here.

```php
public function updateChamp($champ, $newVal, $sim)
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->set($champ,$newVal)
        ->where("numero_sim",$sim)
        ->update("forfait");
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return($this->db->trans_status());
}
```

Here, an old version of my function :

```php
public function updateChamp($champ, $newVal, $sim)
{  
    return $this->db->set($champ,$newVal)
        ->where("numero_sim",$sim)
        ->update("forfait");
}
```

Comment: have you tried to print the DB errors? please try to catch the DB error with this function`$this->db->error();`, also try to print the executed query by this `$this->db->last_query();` and share the result.

Comment: @Mohammad  It returns :
`$this->db->last_query()` :
`string 'UPDATE forfait SET utilisateur = 'JD0071' WHERE numero_sim = '45632185496195'' (length=83)
`
And 
`$this->db->error()` :

`array (size=2)
  'code' => int 0 
  'message' => string '' (length=0)
`

Comment: Ok after some changes, I have an error message which is displayed by `$this->db->error();`.  
*"Field 'type_type' doesn't have a default value"*  
but this field is not even in the same table i'm working on.

Comment: Ok it's because i've forgotten that i've a trigger on this update.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem.
I forgot that I made a trigger which insert data in another table and the problem was that this table had a column which can not be null but it didn't have a default value. And as i wasn't giving a value for this column in my trigger, `$this->db->update()` was returning false.